# Python: How can we smooth a noisy signal using moving average?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random-forest, convolution, moving-average

For an evaluation of a random forest regression, I am trying to improve a result using a `moving average filter` after fitting a model using a `RandomForestRegressor` for a dataset found in [this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Iv8dfU4fTUdlE0VUJKUnctSkE)

```
import pandas as pd
import math
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor, GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_squared_error, make_scorer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split


n_features=3000

df = pd.read_csv('cubic32.csv')

for i in range(1,n_features):
    df['X_t'+str(i)] = df['X'].shift(i)

print(df)

df.dropna(inplace=True)


X = df.drop('Y', axis=1)
y = df['Y']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.40)

X_train = X_train.drop('time', axis=1)
X_test = X_test.drop('time', axis=1)


parameters = {'n_estimators': [10]}
clf_rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1)
clf = GridSearchCV(clf_rf, parameters, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', n_jobs=-1)
model = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
model.cv_results_['params'][model.best_index_]
math.sqrt(model.best_score_*-1)
model.grid_scores_

#####
print()
print(model.grid_scores_)
print("The best score: ",model.best_score_)

print("RMSE:",math.sqrt(model.best_score_*-1))

clf_rf.fit(X_train,y_train)
modelPrediction = clf_rf.predict(X_test)
print(modelPrediction)

print("Number of predictions:",len(modelPrediction))

meanSquaredError=mean_squared_error(y_test, modelPrediction)
print("Mean Square Error (MSE):", meanSquaredError)
rootMeanSquaredError = sqrt(meanSquaredError)
print("Root-Mean-Square Error (RMSE):", rootMeanSquaredError)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
index_values=range(0,len(y_test))

y_test.sort_index(inplace=True)
X_test.sort_index(inplace=True)

modelPred_test = clf_rf.predict(X_test)
ax.plot(pd.Series(index_values), y_test.values)

smoothed = np.convolve(modelPred_test, np.ones(10)/10)
PlotInOne=pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([pd.Series(smoothed), pd.Series(y_test.values)], axis=1))
plt.figure(); PlotInOne.plot(); plt.legend(loc='best')
```

However, the plot of the predicted values seems (as shown below) to be very coarse (the blue line) even if i am smoothing the prediction values like the following

```
smoothed = np.convolve(modelPred_test, np.ones(10)/10)
```

The orange line is a plot of the actual value.

[image]

Is there any way that we can penalize the prediction error (or smooth the noise of the signal using a moving average or other smoothing techniques) so that we get a plot closer to the actual value? I am also trying to increase the number of estimators for the random forest tree (`n_estimators`), but it doesn't seem to improve much. If we plot the actual value alone, it looks like the following.

[image]

Comment: As a suggestion, you could use Github Gists to store sample datasets (and scripts if available).

Comment: OK, I will do that from now on and thanks.

Comment: fYou could try a larger smoothing window, in general you will lose some of the noise, but at the same time probably lose some of the general "shape" to the data. Try messing around with different sized windows, like `np.ones(50)/50` or something like that.

Comment: @DestaHaileselassieHagos can you please upload your file somewhere and update the link. I am trying to understand this code and run this but your file doesn't exist on above given link. Thanks in advance